# How to take directory path as a user input on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, directory

I'm trying to develop a UI that allows users to open a menu, set a directory, input a file name (word doc) and execute a set of tasks to the file and save a new modified file in the same directory/location of the old file.

However, I immediately get an error when I try and set the directory. Here is my code:

```
def menu():
""" the main user-interaction loop
"""
    Cuts = ""

    while True:
        display_menu()
        choice = int(input('Enter your choice: '))
        print()

        if choice == 0:
            print('input directory')
            x = input()
            os.chdir(x)
```

I get the following error when I try to do it:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: "'C:\\Users\\NAME\\Desktop'"
```

This is so strange considering when I do it directly on the script/ the shell it works!

In fact one of the first lines of my code are:
os.chdir(C:/Users/NAME/Desktop')- which works perfectly.

I know for Windows there's this discussion about "/" being an escape - a concept I partially understand, but I've already tried numerous alternatives using "\" instead of "/" or using "//". Also looked into using raw_input but I'm on 3.6 so that function doesn't even work.

Any insight/help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception you should always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k).

Comment: You need to use the OS primitive to build your path. os.path.join(xx, yy, cc) that will produce a valid path xx/yy/cc

Comment: Based on the error, I guess you entered your input enclosed by single quotes? You should omit using quotes when typing strings for the `input` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your error message:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: "'C:\\Users\\NAME\\Desktop'"
```

I guess you entered `'C:\Users\NAME\Desktop'` into the `input` prompt. Omit quotes (`''`) and then you should be good to go.

Otherwise you will end up passing this string to `os.chdir`: `"'C:\Users\NAME\Desktop'"` which is not a valid path.

Comment: @Pymateur Glad to hear! Can you accept my post as an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

With the Os primitive, your code would look something like:

```
x = input()
path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), x)
os.chdir(path)
```

That will navigate from your current directory

Comment: Hi, thanks everyone for replying, I'm new here. but I'll put in the traceback above^ in an edit.